# Android ImageView size unexpectedly changing at runtime

Tags: android, image, view, imageview, scale

In one of my activities, I have a table layout with cells that are added at runtime via a custom class. The layout for my cells is as follows:

```
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+cell/style_2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" >

        <View
            android:id="@+cell/divider"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="2dp"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:background="#FF000000" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+cell/image"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_below="@cell/divider"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:contentDescription="@string/row_thumbnail"
            android:scaleType="fitCenter"/>
    </RelativeLayout>

</TableRow>
```

This gets inflated by the following class:

```
public Cell(Context context) {
    super(context);

    addView(((LayoutInflater) context
        .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
        .inflate(R.layout.gallery_row_1, null));
}
```

When I inflate the cell, I also set an image to be used as a display, the problem is that the size of the image view is not staying as it should, the right edge is nowhere to be found, and the image is never displayed (probably way off to the right somewhere?), and I am not sure where my problem lies.

```
c = new Cell(this);
c.getImageView().setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(assetManager.open("categories" + File.separator + sec + File.separator + filename)));
page.addView(c);
```

`getImageView` being a function in my Cell that returns the actual ImageView element.

I know the image is being placed in the ImageView, because when layout params are changed, I can see the image, just not sized appropriately.

The desired output should be a view, a dividing view on top, and an ImageView below, that fills the parent and is 100dp tall. The image, no matter the origional size, should be scaled and shown inside.

Also, if I comment out the line where I set the image to the ImageView, the layout bounds are correct, as viewed with `Show Layout Bounds` enabled.

My overall question is, why is my ImageView being re-sized when I apply an image.

Any and all help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See [this post on LayoutInflater](http://www.doubleencore.com/2013/05/layout-inflation-as-intended/) for why your layout is getting mixed up. Since it seems your cell class is an inner class of some `ViewGroup` (since you're calling `addView()`), try using the following code:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_row_1, this);
```

or

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_row_1, this, false);
addView (view);
```

instead of using

```
inflater.inflate(R.layout.gallery_row_1, null);
```

The `inflate()` call uses the second parameter (the container) to determine what type of `LayoutParams` to use to interpret the XML. If you pass null, all of the layout attributes are ignored. You should instead either call it with the actual container (which will automatically add it to the container) or call it with the container, and a third parameter telling it not to attach the view yet, and then do what you want with the inflated view.

Comment: I love you. Thanks! :D I spent a solid 2 hours playing around with the XML config trying to make everything sit right...